# XML Spy Blocks Weblogic 10.3.2

Tags: java, weblogic, xmlspy

My computer was shut down abruptly and since then i'm not able to run weblogic (10.3.2) locally on my computer ( neither from eclipse or manually from the oracle domain) .
i keep getting the message:
`\Altova\xmlspy\XMLSpyInterface.jar` was unexpected at this time.

i deleted all of what is related to xmlspy and i still get this error.
any ideas what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the error snippet you provided it looks like you have set some Environment Variable for XMLSpy which is causing problem while starting up the JVM. Do have a look at your System Environment Variable and remove the variables in %PATH% which have SPACE.

This should resolve your issue.